# Show page differently (css) if within iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, iframe

Is there any way to, as the title says "Show page differently (css) if within iframe". I'm looking for a jQuery / JavaScript method to potentially use a different css stylesheet if the site is within an iframe. Any ideas?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You can [inject](http://xtrahot.chili-mango.net/2005/09/peoplesoft-page-stylesheet-injectionhtml/) a different stylesheet if the window is not the [top window](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_win_top.asp).

```
if (window.top!=window.self)
{
  // In a Frame or IFrame
}
else
{
  // Not in a frame
}
```

Comment: Is there a purely CSS method to accomplish this or is checking `window.top` via JavaScript required?

Comment: @iX3 - there isn't . CSS is not aware of frames.

Answer (score 19):

Rather than inject a new stylesheet, I would suggest adding a CSS class to `body`.

jQuery example:

```
$(function() {
  if (window.self != window.top) {
    $(document.body).addClass("in-iframe");
  }
});
```

Now you can style things differently like

```
.in-iframe p {
  background: purple;
}
```

Comment: ^this. Going with a whole new css file is probably overkill for most practical uses.

Answer (score 14):

Here is a fast and designer friendly approach using vanilla JS. Just one line of JS and the look and feel can be controlled from CSS/SASS/LESS.

Place this within the `head` element before any CSS or JS is loaded:

```
// Sets the class of the HTML element using vanilla JavaScript
document.documentElement.className += (window.self == window.top ? " top" : " framed");
```

Then in your CSS/SASS/LESS you can hide, show, and tweak based on which class was applied.

```
/* Hide site navigation when in an iframe */
html.framed .site-nav,
html.framed .site-footer {
    display: none;
}
```

PSA: Consider taking advantage of the [X-Frame-Options](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/X-Frame-Options) to keep your hard work from being hijacked.

Comment: This is just neat, clean and self explanatory, I like it !

Comment: this is the way i ended up doing it. very smart Jeremy. short and simple.

Answer (score 4):

```
if( self != top ) {
   headTag = document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].innerHTML;
   var frameCSS = headTag + '<style type="text/css">**insert CSS here**</style>';
   document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].innerHTML = frameCSS;
}
```

If the page is the only page being displayed, top, parent, self and window will be equal. If the page is being held within a frameset, self and top will not be equal. If the page is the page containing the frameset, and it itself is not being held within a frameset, self and top will be equal.